# PAClient Error: E2312 ERROR: resource directory '<project path>\res' does not exist

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

If I make a new project and then try to run it, I get this error:

> [PAClient Error] Error: E2312 ERROR: resource directory '\res' does not exist

I know that this error can be solved by defining icons in 
`Project -> Options -> Application`, but shouldn't Delphi have some icons defined by 
default? I get the same error on brand new installations on two 
machines. How do I fix this so I have some default icons defined for all 
projects I create?

**Edit:** The Delphi XE5 install was done without any iPhone or mac support. Just android and Windows. To reproduce, on my machines I create a new project I go to 
`File -> New -> FireMonkey Mobile Application -> Blank Application`

Save the project and run it.

The .dproj file created by the IDE by default android icons missing (Search in the two files for Cfg_1_Android):

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ProjectGuid>{268A9436-E977-4E52-A39B-E59974DE4C31}</ProjectGuid>
        <ProjectVersion>15.3</ProjectVersion>
        <FrameworkType>FMX</FrameworkType>
        <MainSource>Project2.dpr</MainSource>
        <Base>True</Base>
        <Config Condition="'$(Config)'==''">Debug</Config>
        <Platform Condition="'$(Platform)'==''">Android</Platform>
        <TargetedPlatforms>16</TargetedPlatforms>
        <AppType>Application</AppType>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Base' or '$(Base)'!=''">
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Android' and '$(Base)'=='true') or '$(Base_Android)'!=''">
        <Base_Android>true</Base_Android>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Win32' and '$(Base)'=='true') or '$(Base_Win32)'!=''">
        <Base_Win32>true</Base_Win32>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Debug' or '$(Cfg_1)'!=''">
        <Cfg_1>true</Cfg_1>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Win32' and '$(Cfg_1)'=='true') or '$(Cfg_1_Win32)'!=''">
        <Cfg_1_Win32>true</Cfg_1_Win32>
        <CfgParent>Cfg_1</CfgParent>
        <Cfg_1>true</Cfg_1>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Release' or '$(Cfg_2)'!=''">
        <Cfg_2>true</Cfg_2>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base)'!=''">
        <DCC_Namespace>System;Xml;Data;Datasnap;Web;Soap;$(DCC_Namespace)</DCC_Namespace>
        <DCC_DcuOutput>.\$(Platform)\$(Config)</DCC_DcuOutput>
        <DCC_ExeOutput>.\$(Platform)\$(Config)</DCC_ExeOutput>
        <DCC_E>false</DCC_E>
        <DCC_N>false</DCC_N>
        <DCC_S>false</DCC_S>
        <DCC_F>false</DCC_F>
        <DCC_K>false</DCC_K>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base_Android)'!=''">
        <DCC_UsePackage>FireDACSqliteDriver;bindcompfmx;DBXSqliteDriver;fmx;rtl;dbrtl;DbxClientDriver;IndySystem;FireDACCommon;bindcomp;DBXInterBaseDriver;DataSnapClient;DataSnapCommon;DataSnapProviderClient;xmlrtl;ibxpress;DbxCommonDriver;IndyProtocols;dbxcds;FireDACCommonDriver;bindengine;soaprtl;bindcompdbx;fmxFireDAC;CustomIPTransport;FireDAC;dsnap;IndyCore;FireDACDataSnapDriver;IndyIPCommon;CloudService;FireDACIBDriver;inet;FireDACDBXDriver;DataSnapFireDAC;RESTComponents;dbexpress;IndyIPClient;$(DCC_UsePackage)</DCC_UsePackage>
        <VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>true</VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>
        <BT_BuildType>Debug</BT_BuildType>
        <VerInfo_Keys>package=com.embarcadero.$(MSBuildProjectName);label=$(MSBuildProjectName);versionCode=1;versionName=1.0.0;persistent=False;restoreAnyVersion=False;installLocation=preferExternal;largeHeap=False;theme=TitleBar</VerInfo_Keys>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base_Win32)'!=''">
        <DCC_UsePackage>DataSnapIndy10ServerTransport;FireDACASADriver;FireDACSqliteDriver;bindcompfmx;DBXSqliteDriver;vcldbx;FireDACPgDriver;FireDACODBCDriver;fmx;rtl;dbrtl;DbxClientDriver;IndySystem;FireDACCommon;bindcomp;inetdb;vclib;inetdbbde;DBXInterBaseDriver;DataSnapClient;DataSnapCommon;DBXOdbcDriver;DataSnapServer;vclFireDAC;DataSnapProviderClient;xmlrtl;svnui;ibxpress;DbxCommonDriver;DBXSybaseASEDriver;vclimg;IndyProtocols;dbxcds;DBXMySQLDriver;DatasnapConnectorsFreePascal;FireDACCommonDriver;MetropolisUILiveTile;bindengine;vclactnband;vcldb;soaprtl;bindcompdbx;vcldsnap;bindcompvcl;vclie;fmxFireDAC;FireDACADSDriver;vcltouch;DBXDb2Driver;DBXOracleDriver;CustomIPTransport;VclSmp;FireDACMSSQLDriver;FireDAC;dsnap;IndyIPServer;fmxase;vcl;IndyCore;FireDACDataSnapDriver;VCLRESTComponents;IndyIPCommon;CloudService;DBXMSSQLDriver;dsnapcon;FireDACIBDriver;DBXFirebirdDriver;inet;DBXInformixDriver;fmxobj;FireDACDBXDriver;DataSnapFireDAC;DataSnapConnectors;FireDACMySQLDriver;vclx;inetdbxpress;svn;DBXSybaseASADriver;FireDACOracleDriver;fmxdae;FireDACDb2Driver;RESTComponents;bdertl;FireDACMSAccDriver;adortl;dbexpress;IndyIPClient;$(DCC_UsePackage)</DCC_UsePackage>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_1)'!=''">
        <DCC_Define>DEBUG;$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
        <DCC_DebugDCUs>true</DCC_DebugDCUs>
        <DCC_Optimize>false</DCC_Optimize>
        <DCC_GenerateStackFrames>true</DCC_GenerateStackFrames>
        <DCC_DebugInfoInExe>true</DCC_DebugInfoInExe>
        <DCC_RemoteDebug>true</DCC_RemoteDebug>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_1_Win32)'!=''">
        <DCC_RemoteDebug>false</DCC_RemoteDebug>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_2)'!=''">
        <DCC_LocalDebugSymbols>false</DCC_LocalDebugSymbols>
        <DCC_Define>RELEASE;$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
        <DCC_SymbolReferenceInfo>0</DCC_SymbolReferenceInfo>
        <DCC_DebugInformation>0</DCC_DebugInformation>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <DelphiCompile Include="$(MainSource)">
            <MainSource>MainSource</MainSource>
        </DelphiCompile>
        <DCCReference Include="Unit2.pas">
            <Form>Form2</Form>
            <FormType>fmx</FormType>
        </DCCReference>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Release">
            <Key>Cfg_2</Key>
            <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        </BuildConfiguration>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Base">
            <Key>Base</Key>
        </BuildConfiguration>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Debug">
            <Key>Cfg_1</Key>
            <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        </BuildConfiguration>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ProjectExtensions>
        <Borland.Personality>Delphi.Personality.12</Borland.Personality>
        <Borland.ProjectType/>
        <BorlandProject>
            <Delphi.Personality>
                <VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="IncludeVerInfo">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="AutoIncBuild">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="MajorVer">1</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="MinorVer">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Release">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Build">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Debug">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="PreRelease">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Special">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Private">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="DLL">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Locale">1033</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="CodePage">1252</VersionInfo>
                </VersionInfo>
                <VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CompanyName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="FileDescription"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="FileVersion">1.0.0.0</VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="InternalName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LegalCopyright"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LegalTrademarks"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="OriginalFilename"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="ProductName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="ProductVersion">1.0.0.0</VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="Comments"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleDisplayName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="UIDeviceFamily"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleIdentifier"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleVersion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundlePackageType"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleSignature"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleExecutable"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleResourceSpecification"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LSRequiresIPhoneOS"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="package"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="label"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="versionCode"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="versionName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="persistent"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="restoreAnyVersion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="installLocation"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="largeHeap"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="theme"/>
                </VersionInfoKeys>
                <Source>
                    <Source Name="MainSource">Project2.dpr</Source>
                </Source>
            </Delphi.Personality>
            <Deployment/>
            <Platforms>
                <Platform value="Android" ActiveMobileDevice="rsxe5_android">True</Platform>
                <Platform value="iOSDevice">False</Platform>
                <Platform value="iOSSimulator">False</Platform>
                <Platform value="Win32">False</Platform>
            </Platforms>
        </BorlandProject>
        <ProjectFileVersion>12</ProjectFileVersion>
    </ProjectExtensions>
    <Import Project="$(BDS)\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets" Condition="Exists('$(BDS)\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets')"/>
    <Import Project="$(APPDATA)\Embarcadero\$(BDSAPPDATABASEDIR)\$(PRODUCTVERSION)\UserTools.proj" Condition="Exists('$(APPDATA)\Embarcadero\$(BDSAPPDATABASEDIR)\$(PRODUCTVERSION)\UserTools.proj')"/>
</Project>
```

If I add the icons manually `Project -> Options -> Application` the .dproj file looks like this (the icons are added, and I don't get the error anymore):

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ProjectGuid>{B6BE98F1-101D-4464-B359-25DFA056D37C}</ProjectGuid>
        <ProjectVersion>15.3</ProjectVersion>
        <FrameworkType>FMX</FrameworkType>
        <MainSource>Project1.dpr</MainSource>
        <Base>True</Base>
        <Config Condition="'$(Config)'==''">Debug</Config>
        <Platform Condition="'$(Platform)'==''">Android</Platform>
        <TargetedPlatforms>16</TargetedPlatforms>
        <AppType>Application</AppType>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Base' or '$(Base)'!=''">
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Android' and '$(Base)'=='true') or '$(Base_Android)'!=''">
        <Base_Android>true</Base_Android>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Win32' and '$(Base)'=='true') or '$(Base_Win32)'!=''">
        <Base_Win32>true</Base_Win32>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Debug' or '$(Cfg_1)'!=''">
        <Cfg_1>true</Cfg_1>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Android' and '$(Cfg_1)'=='true') or '$(Cfg_1_Android)'!=''">
        <Cfg_1_Android>true</Cfg_1_Android>
        <CfgParent>Cfg_1</CfgParent>
        <Cfg_1>true</Cfg_1>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Win32' and '$(Cfg_1)'=='true') or '$(Cfg_1_Win32)'!=''">
        <Cfg_1_Win32>true</Cfg_1_Win32>
        <CfgParent>Cfg_1</CfgParent>
        <Cfg_1>true</Cfg_1>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Release' or '$(Cfg_2)'!=''">
        <Cfg_2>true</Cfg_2>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base)'!=''">
        <DCC_Namespace>System;Xml;Data;Datasnap;Web;Soap;$(DCC_Namespace)</DCC_Namespace>
        <DCC_DcuOutput>.\$(Platform)\$(Config)</DCC_DcuOutput>
        <DCC_ExeOutput>.\$(Platform)\$(Config)</DCC_ExeOutput>
        <DCC_E>false</DCC_E>
        <DCC_N>false</DCC_N>
        <DCC_S>false</DCC_S>
        <DCC_F>false</DCC_F>
        <DCC_K>false</DCC_K>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base_Android)'!=''">
        <VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>true</VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>
        <DCC_UsePackage>FireDACSqliteDriver;bindcompfmx;DBXSqliteDriver;fmx;rtl;dbrtl;DbxClientDriver;IndySystem;FireDACCommon;bindcomp;DBXInterBaseDriver;DataSnapClient;DataSnapCommon;DataSnapProviderClient;xmlrtl;ibxpress;DbxCommonDriver;IndyProtocols;dbxcds;FireDACCommonDriver;bindengine;soaprtl;bindcompdbx;fmxFireDAC;CustomIPTransport;FireDAC;dsnap;IndyCore;FireDACDataSnapDriver;IndyIPCommon;CloudService;FireDACIBDriver;inet;FireDACDBXDriver;DataSnapFireDAC;RESTComponents;dbexpress;IndyIPClient;$(DCC_UsePackage)</DCC_UsePackage>
        <BT_BuildType>Debug</BT_BuildType>
        <VerInfo_Keys>package=com.embarcadero.$(MSBuildProjectName);label=$(MSBuildProjectName);versionCode=1;versionName=1.0.0;persistent=False;restoreAnyVersion=False;installLocation=preferExternal;largeHeap=False;theme=TitleBar</VerInfo_Keys>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base_Win32)'!=''">
        <DCC_UsePackage>DataSnapIndy10ServerTransport;FireDACASADriver;FireDACSqliteDriver;bindcompfmx;DBXSqliteDriver;vcldbx;FireDACPgDriver;FireDACODBCDriver;fmx;rtl;dbrtl;DbxClientDriver;IndySystem;FireDACCommon;bindcomp;inetdb;vclib;inetdbbde;DBXInterBaseDriver;DataSnapClient;DataSnapCommon;DBXOdbcDriver;DataSnapServer;vclFireDAC;DataSnapProviderClient;xmlrtl;svnui;ibxpress;DbxCommonDriver;DBXSybaseASEDriver;vclimg;IndyProtocols;dbxcds;DBXMySQLDriver;DatasnapConnectorsFreePascal;FireDACCommonDriver;MetropolisUILiveTile;bindengine;vclactnband;vcldb;soaprtl;bindcompdbx;vcldsnap;bindcompvcl;vclie;fmxFireDAC;FireDACADSDriver;vcltouch;DBXDb2Driver;DBXOracleDriver;CustomIPTransport;VclSmp;FireDACMSSQLDriver;FireDAC;dsnap;IndyIPServer;fmxase;vcl;IndyCore;FireDACDataSnapDriver;VCLRESTComponents;IndyIPCommon;CloudService;DBXMSSQLDriver;dsnapcon;FireDACIBDriver;DBXFirebirdDriver;inet;DBXInformixDriver;fmxobj;FireDACDBXDriver;DataSnapFireDAC;DataSnapConnectors;FireDACMySQLDriver;vclx;inetdbxpress;svn;DBXSybaseASADriver;FireDACOracleDriver;fmxdae;FireDACDb2Driver;RESTComponents;bdertl;FireDACMSAccDriver;adortl;dbexpress;IndyIPClient;$(DCC_UsePackage)</DCC_UsePackage>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_1)'!=''">
        <DCC_Define>DEBUG;$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
        <DCC_DebugDCUs>true</DCC_DebugDCUs>
        <DCC_Optimize>false</DCC_Optimize>
        <DCC_GenerateStackFrames>true</DCC_GenerateStackFrames>
        <DCC_DebugInfoInExe>true</DCC_DebugInfoInExe>
        <DCC_RemoteDebug>true</DCC_RemoteDebug>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_1_Android)'!=''">
        <Android_LauncherIcon72>C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\bin\Artwork\Android\FM_LauncherIcon_72x72.png</Android_LauncherIcon72>
        <Android_LauncherIcon96>C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\bin\Artwork\Android\FM_LauncherIcon_96x96.png</Android_LauncherIcon96>
        <Android_LauncherIcon36>C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\bin\Artwork\Android\FM_LauncherIcon_36x36.png</Android_LauncherIcon36>
        <Android_LauncherIcon48>C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\bin\Artwork\Android\FM_LauncherIcon_48x48.png</Android_LauncherIcon48>
        <VerInfo_Build>1</VerInfo_Build>
        <Android_LauncherIcon144>C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\bin\Artwork\Android\FM_LauncherIcon_144x144.png</Android_LauncherIcon144>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_1_Win32)'!=''">
        <DCC_RemoteDebug>false</DCC_RemoteDebug>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_2)'!=''">
        <DCC_LocalDebugSymbols>false</DCC_LocalDebugSymbols>
        <DCC_Define>RELEASE;$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
        <DCC_SymbolReferenceInfo>0</DCC_SymbolReferenceInfo>
        <DCC_DebugInformation>0</DCC_DebugInformation>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <DelphiCompile Include="$(MainSource)">
            <MainSource>MainSource</MainSource>
        </DelphiCompile>
        <DCCReference Include="Unit1.pas">
            <Form>Form1</Form>
            <FormType>fmx</FormType>
        </DCCReference>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Release">
            <Key>Cfg_2</Key>
            <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        </BuildConfiguration>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Base">
            <Key>Base</Key>
        </BuildConfiguration>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Debug">
            <Key>Cfg_1</Key>
            <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        </BuildConfiguration>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ProjectExtensions>
        <Borland.Personality>Delphi.Personality.12</Borland.Personality>
        <Borland.ProjectType/>
        <BorlandProject>
            <Delphi.Personality>
                <VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="IncludeVerInfo">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="AutoIncBuild">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="MajorVer">1</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="MinorVer">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Release">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Build">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Debug">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="PreRelease">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Special">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Private">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="DLL">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Locale">1033</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="CodePage">1252</VersionInfo>
                </VersionInfo>
                <VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CompanyName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="FileDescription"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="FileVersion">1.0.0.0</VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="InternalName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LegalCopyright"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LegalTrademarks"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="OriginalFilename"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="ProductName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="ProductVersion">1.0.0.0</VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="Comments"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleDisplayName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="UIDeviceFamily"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleIdentifier"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleVersion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundlePackageType"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleSignature"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleExecutable"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleResourceSpecification"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LSRequiresIPhoneOS"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="package"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="label"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="versionCode"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="versionName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="persistent"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="restoreAnyVersion"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="installLocation"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="largeHeap"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="theme"/>
                </VersionInfoKeys>
                <Source>
                    <Source Name="MainSource">Project1.dpr</Source>
                </Source>
                <Excluded_Packages>
                    <Excluded_Packages Name="$(BDSBIN)\dcloffice2k190.bpl">Microsoft Office 2000 Sample Automation Server Wrapper Components</Excluded_Packages>
                    <Excluded_Packages Name="$(BDSBIN)\dclofficexp190.bpl">Microsoft Office XP Sample Automation Server Wrapper Components</Excluded_Packages>
                </Excluded_Packages>
            </Delphi.Personality>
            <Deployment/>
            <Platforms>
                <Platform value="Android" ActiveMobileDevice="rsxe5_android">True</Platform>
                <Platform value="iOSDevice">False</Platform>
                <Platform value="iOSSimulator">False</Platform>
                <Platform value="Win32">False</Platform>
            </Platforms>
        </BorlandProject>
        <ProjectFileVersion>12</ProjectFileVersion>
    </ProjectExtensions>
    <Import Project="$(BDS)\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets" Condition="Exists('$(BDS)\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets')"/>
    <Import Project="$(APPDATA)\Embarcadero\$(BDSAPPDATABASEDIR)\$(PRODUCTVERSION)\UserTools.proj" Condition="Exists('$(APPDATA)\Embarcadero\$(BDSAPPDATABASEDIR)\$(PRODUCTVERSION)\UserTools.proj')"/>
</Project>
```

Meaningful differences are bolded.

Comment: How can I reproduce this? I've got many new Android projects, and haven't seen this at all. Can you [edit] your question to provide the *specific steps* you followed to create your project and try to run it?

Comment: Done. I attached the .dproj files, the one created by default by the IDE (with the icons missing) and the one with the icons, after I added them manually.

Comment: There's a lot more to starting to develop with Android (and even after that, a couple of initial steps you have to take with each project) before you can just "run your application", including configuring your computer, starting the emulator or connecting a device, and selecting the appropriate target using the Project Manager. Follow the tutorial in the help file to get started. The [online docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Mobile_Tutorial%3A_Creating_a_FireMonkey_Mobile_Application_%28iOS_and_Android%29) start here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic steps that are covered in the product documentation that weren't followed, and are far too broad to be answered here.

Comment: If you prefer the off-line tutorial, open the help file, select the "Contents" tab, and see "RAD Studio, RAD Studio Topics, Tutorials, Cross-Platform Tutorials, Mobile Tutorials".

Comment: @KenWhite I'm not a beginner in Delphi, I know how to develop an application and I've seen, read and watched most of the docs/videos for android development. Your answer still doesn't answer my question, how do I make a set of icons to be by default linked to a new created project. Like I said in my post, I can link them manually and then everything works, I can deploy to the phone etc... Is this how the IDE is supposed to work, no default icons for android mobile apps? I'm pretty sure that this is a bug.

Comment: The tutorials explain all of that, including where (and how) to include icons and other resources in your projects. (I also asked you to provide specific steps to reproduce it, and your response was "File->New" and then save and run. Nowhere do you mention starting an emulator, configuring the target, or any of the other steps that are involved before you can just "run" an Android app. It's far from clear that you've any experience, based on that response. PAServer is only required for Mac/iOS development, so you clearly haven't configured a target.)

Comment: @KenWhite So you are telling me that **is normal** that the IDE doesn't put some default icons when a new android firemonkey project is created? My question has NOTHING to do with the emulator, if you look again at my original post "I know that this error can be solved by defining icons in Project -> Options -> Application, but shouldn't Delphi have some icons defined by default?".

Comment: No, I'm telling you that if you properly configure the target, it **will** in fact include default icons (they're an FMX flame on a black background). If you want to use the defaults, it works fine. The tutorial describes how to use your own custom icons in place of the defaults.

Comment: @KenWhite  "it will in fact include default icons". Well, that's the problem I'm talking about. On two different installs the default icons are NOT included in a new project. If I create a new project, put a button on a form... etc then start the emulator (or set the phone as target) and I try to run, I get the error from the subject because there aren't any icons defined. If I go to  Project -> Options -> Application and add some icons and run again, the app works fine.

Comment: Please read everything I've written above again. If you **properly** configure the environment, create a new application, and set the target, not only is PAServer not even involved in an Android app, but the default icons **are** created (and deployed with either a debug or release build). You are **not properly configuring the target for your project** before trying to execute it. I don't know how many times I can repeat that before you'll actually read the words, so I'm going to stop at that one. It's either that, or I copy the phrase to the clipboard so I can just paste it next time. :-)

Comment: "You are not properly configuring the target for your project before trying to execute it." <- You still don't get it. I CAN RUN the applications, on the emulator AND on the phone, no problems at all there, but ONLY after assigning manually the icons for the project. The IDE doesn't assign them (just look at the first file). The whole android emulator is configured correctly and I can run the applications made in delphi just fine! See this http://i.imgur.com/QV5dkyY.jpg, that's how a new project is created. No icons. If I assign some icons works, if I don't I get the error.

Comment: No, I'm afraid I do get it. I can connect my S3 or Nexus 7, start a new FMX mobile app, choose an Android blank application, set the target in the project manager to the proper device, and build my application, and then run it. It properly appears on the device with the proper icon, runs, and all is well. If you're properly creating the app and setting the target, the **default icons are added automatically**.

Comment: @KenWhite Fixed. Uninstalling, cleaning the registry of everything RAD 12 related and installing again did the trick.

Comment: So it was an entirely localized problem on your machine, and not an issue with Delphi in general; that explains why I couldn't reproduce it. Glad to hear you sorted it out. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite so far so good, but it could still be a Delphi bug. When I have time I'll try another installation. On both machines where I had the problem I installed just windows and android support, no iphone or any kind of mac support. Now I installed with iphone and mac support and the problem is gone. I'll have to do again an install just with android and windows support and if the problem is back, I'll report it as a bug to embarcadero.

Comment: It's only a Delphi bug if you can provide steps for someone else (other than you) to reproduce it.

Comment: Yeah, **if** the problem is still there after another install, then the steps to reproduce are the following: 1. Install with no apple support :-)

Comment: OK. If you think that's a viable set of steps to reproduce, please post it as a bug at [QC](http://qc.embarcadero.com) and see what they think. ;-)

Comment: It is a bug. If you install Delphi XE5 with no mac support, you'll have the problem above (I've tested on two different machines). [I filled a bug to QC](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=121302).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>**FIXED.** I uninstalled Delphi and cleaned the registry of everything I found about RAD Studio 12.0 and installed again. Now the default icons are assigned to new projects.</strike>

This is a bug. If you install Delphi XE5 with no OS X or iOS support, you will run into this problem. I filled a bug report [here](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=121302).

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen this error in XE6 when using a project imported from AppMethod. The paths to the launcher icons contain an extra "\AppMethod" in them, which when removed will fix this error.

Answer (score -1):

Taken from:
[How to set up your RAD Studio Delphi development environment to create Android apps](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/43415)
By: Tim DelChiaro

```
 Select Tools > Options > Environment Options > SDK Manager.

    Here is the SDK Manager when it is fully populated with the recommended Android SDK: 
    SDKManager.png

    Note:
        The SDK Manager fields are blank if the SDK Manager cannot detect the default installed Android SDK and you have not yet added an Android SDK to the SDK Manager.
        Fields that are marked with YellowBang.png do not have the correct path. Click the [...] in that field and browse to the installed location of the library files. 

Click Add.
On the Add a New SDK dialog box, click the down-arrow in the Select an SDK version field, and select Add New... from the drop-down list:

    AddNewSDKpage.png 
    Note: If your installed Android SDK is listed in the Select an SDK version list, select your Android SDK.

The Create a new Android SDK wizard is displayed.
    Complete the first two fields on this wizard: Android SDK Base Path and Android NDK Base Path (their installed locations). Either enter the paths of the installed locations or click the ellipsis [...] and navigate to the installed locations.
    The YellowBang.png symbol indicates that the base paths are missing, and the Next button is enabled only after these fields are filled.
    Here is the wizard when no SDKs have been added and the base path fields are empty:

        AndDevKitEmpty.png

        This wizard verifies the base paths you specify and then auto-populates the paths to the various other libraries (that is, the tools on page 2 of the wizard). 
        Thus, you might need to enter only the base paths for the NDK and SDK, on page 1 of the wizard. Then the second page will auto-populate, if given a little time. Or you might need to verify the auto-populated addresses (if they are present). 

    Here is the first page of the wizard after you browse to (or enter) the paths to the Android SDK and NDK. There are no YellowBang.png icons because the paths have been verified.

        PathsComplete.png

Click Next to go to the next page of the wizard, where the wizard will attempt to prefill the fields by discovery.
    Here is the second page of the wizard with all its fields prefilled:

        PrefIlledFields.png

    For any fields that do not prefill, click the ellipsis [...] button and browse to the installed location. 
Click Finish to close the wizard.
```

You can view and manage your installed Android SDKs by opening the SDK Manager.

Comment: Hi it appears you copied the content from http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/43415, without mentioning the source and the author. Plagiarism isn't welcomed on stackoverflow. 
[What to do when plagiarism is discovered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered)