# \res does not exist Delphi-XE5

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I have this error but I don't know what can i do.

[image]

I dont deploy project.
How can fix it?

Comment: It would help if you pasted the error as text rather than an unreadable screenshot with a tantalizing horizontal scroll bar

Comment: By the looks of the scrollbar he is using Windows 8, amazing groundbreaking info!

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/q/20688226/1429387

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(if you made backup your files as written on the readme file)
You must get back to previous session before Hotfix #2

Otherwise you have to install Delphi XE5 again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the <kbd>Project</kbd> -> <kbd>Options</kbd>, choose <kbd>Application</kbd>.
And manually set launcher icons for your Android application. After this folder `\res` should appear and the application should deploy without error.

*Additional:*

- Standard icons are in `$(BDS)\bin\Artwork\Android\`.
- It looks like a bug in the IDE (I don't believe that you yourself deleted icons and now suffer from this issue:D); AFAIK, if you install Delphi XE5 with no OS X or iOS support, you will run into this problem..

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen this error in XE6 when using a project imported from AppMethod. The paths to the launcher icons contain an extra "\AppMethod" in them, which when removed will fix this error.